# save array as image, imwrite matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

Few years ago I used this way to make black and white noise:

```
A=randn(300,300);
B=A*255;
C=ceil(B);
imwrite(C,'noise300.jpeg'). %% or A=rand(300,300)
```

Today I keep getting the following mistake:

```
??? Error using ==> imwrite at 457
Can't open file "noise300.jpg" for writing.
You may not have write permission.
```

**Why can't I save an array (double) as jpeg/bmp or whatever as I did with imwrite?**

Here http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/7864 I figured out that between matlab and windows 7 there is a conflict, but I have Vista.

If there is no way to fix imwrite for my case I will appreciate another way of making jpeg with b&w noise.
Thanx, 
Dina.

Comment: works fine on my Matlab (W7), but this looks more like a directory issue or maybe the file you are trying to write to is opened in another program ?

Comment: You could try: 1. changing access permissions to working directory, 2. saving file to different location "C:\noise300.jpg" for example.

Comment: pretty sure this isn't a matlab issue so much as an OS issue.

Comment: Agree it seems to be a permissions issue. I would do several things: 1) make sure you use the same file extension (`.jpg` is mixed with `.jpeg`. I don't know if that is significant?). 2) Make sure there isn't already a file with that name in that place. 3) Use a full path rather than relative path (maybe you are trying to write to your Matlab program directory...?). 4) See if you can write any file to the directory (without using `imwrite`). Somewhere along the way you will find your solution, is my guess.

Comment: Thank you guys, I saved to another folder! Works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for Matlab error

***'Error using imwrite (line 455)
Unable to open file "1.jpg" for writing.  You may not have write permission.'***

lies in the path of current folder. It may seem something like

***'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin'***

It needs to be changed to some other path in D: or any other drive. It works fine there.
Thank you!